# Wpf Columns overlap / do not show

Tags: c#, wpf

Somehow the columns in my Grid only show the second column (the text fields) (and not the labels), where do I go wrong here?

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
Grid grid = new Grid();
ScrollViewer viewer = new ScrollViewer();
Label lbl_Doc = new Label();
Label lbl_ApplicationId = new Label();
TextBox txt_ApplicationId = new TextBox();
Label lbl_ClientId = new Label();
Label lbl_ClientSecret = new Label();
TextBox txt_ClientId = new TextBox();
TextBox txt_ClientSecret = new TextBox();
Button btn_GetAuthorization = new Button();
WebBrowser webbrowser_webbrowser = new WebBrowser()

public Settings()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // add Grid          
    //grid.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,-76.5,79.5);
    // row 1
    RowDefinition rd1 = new RowDefinition();
    rd1.Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Auto);
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd1);
    // row 2
    RowDefinition rd2 = new RowDefinition();
    rd2.Height = new GridLength(15,GridUnitType.Auto);
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd2);
    // row 3
    RowDefinition rd3 = new RowDefinition();
    rd3.Height = new GridLength(15,GridUnitType.Auto);
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd3);
    // row 4
    RowDefinition rd4 = new RowDefinition();
    rd4.Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Auto);
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd4);
    // row 5
    RowDefinition rd5 = new RowDefinition();
    rd5.Height = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Auto);
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd5);
    // column 1
    ColumnDefinition cd1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd1.Width = new GridLength(500, GridUnitType.Auto);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd1);
    // column 2
    ColumnDefinition cd2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd2.Width = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Auto);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd2);

    // Add Documentation           
    lbl_Doc.Content = "Enter values:";
    Grid.SetRow(lbl_Doc, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(lbl_Doc);

    // Add label + input for Google Application Id            
    lbl_ApplicationId.Content = "Google Application Id";
    lbl_ApplicationId.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    //lbl_ApplicationId.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    lbl_ApplicationId.Width = 150;
    //lbl_ApplicationId.Margin = new Thickness(5,35,0,0);
    Grid.SetRow(lbl_ApplicationId, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(lbl_ApplicationId, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(lbl_ApplicationId);

    //txt_ApplicationId.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    //txt_ApplicationId.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    txt_ApplicationId.Height = 23;
    txt_ApplicationId.Width = 420;
    //txt_ApplicationId.Margin = new Thickness(160,36,0,0);
    txt_ApplicationId.FontSize = 10;
    txt_ApplicationId.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    txt_ApplicationId.Text = init_application_id;
    txt_ApplicationId.TextChanged +=txt_TextChanged;
    Grid.SetRow(txt_ApplicationId, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(txt_ApplicationId, 2);
    grid.Children.Add(txt_ApplicationId);

    // Add label + input for Google Client Id           
    lbl_ClientId.Content = "Google Client Id";
    //lbl_ClientId.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    //lbl_ClientId.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    lbl_ClientId.Width = 150;
    //lbl_ClientId.Margin = new Thickness(5, 35, 0, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(lbl_ClientId, 2);
    Grid.SetColumn(lbl_ClientId, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(lbl_ClientId);

    //txt_ClientId.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    //txt_ClientId.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    txt_ClientId.Height = 23;
    txt_ClientId.Width = 420;
    //txt_ClientId.Margin = new Thickness(160, 36, 0, 0);
    txt_ClientId.FontSize = 10;
    txt_ClientId.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    txt_ClientId.TextChanged +=txt_TextChanged;
    txt_ClientId.Text = init_clientid;
    Grid.SetRow(txt_ClientId, 2);
    Grid.SetColumn(txt_ClientId, 2);
    grid.Children.Add(txt_ClientId);

    // Add label + input for Google Client Secret            
    lbl_ClientSecret.Content = "Google Client Secret";
    //lbl_ClientSecret.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    //lbl_ClientSecret.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    lbl_ClientSecret.Width = 150;
    //lbl_ClientSecret.Margin = new Thickness(5, 35, 0, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(lbl_ClientSecret, 3);
    Grid.SetColumn(lbl_ClientSecret, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(lbl_ClientSecret);

    //txt_ClientSecret.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    //txt_ClientSecret.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    txt_ClientSecret.Height = 23;
    txt_ClientSecret.Width = 420;
    //txt_ClientSecret.Margin = new Thickness(160, 36, 0, 0);
    txt_ClientSecret.FontSize = 10;
    txt_ClientSecret.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    txt_ClientSecret.TextChanged +=txt_TextChanged;
    txt_ClientSecret.Text = init_clientSecret;
    Grid.SetRow(txt_ClientSecret, 3);
    Grid.SetColumn(txt_ClientSecret, 2);
    grid.Children.Add(txt_ClientSecret);

    // button to get authorization             
    btn_GetAuthorization.Content = "Authorize";
    //btn_GetAuthorization.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    //btn_GetAuthorization.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    btn_GetAuthorization.Height = 21;
    btn_GetAuthorization.Width = 72;
   // btn_GetAuthorization.Margin = new Thickness(160,120,0,0);
    btn_GetAuthorization.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    btn_GetAuthorization.Click += btn_GetAuthorization_Click;
    Grid.SetRow(btn_GetAuthorization, 4);
    Grid.SetColumn(btn_GetAuthorization, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(btn_GetAuthorization);

    // Add Scrollviewer            
    viewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    viewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    viewer.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    viewer.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    viewer.Content = grid;

    Google_Settings.Content = viewer;
    Google_Settings.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
}
```

Comment: You should not add GUI elements by code-behind in WPF. Please read about MVVM

Comment: Thats another philosophy, When I have fixed this, I need to make them conditionally to be added or not.

Comment: I think you are using wrong IDs for columns `Grid.SetColumn(txt_ApplicationId, 2);`. Indexes are zero based and should be 0 and 1

Comment: Delete all that horrible code and use proper XAML.

Comment: @FlatEric Ah yep, that was it :) Thanx, if you put it in as answer i will mark it as answer

Comment: @HighCore : that was my first iteration long ago

Comment: @edelwater WPF is about XAML and DataBinding, not these horrible procedural code hacks you're incurring in here. Sooner or later you will hit your head against a hard wall if you continue this route. That said, it's your code, not mine.

Comment: @highCore ok ok ok ... changed it back to using XAML and using txt_ApplicationId.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; stuff instead

Comment: @edelwater not really. You should not manipulate UI elements properties in procedural code in WPF. Read about MVVM and `ItemsControls`, If you need to conditionally show/hide elements in an items-based UI, use an `ObservableCollection` and a `CollectionView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the index you are using:

```
Grid.SetColumn(txt_ApplicationId, 2);
```

It is zero based and the values must be `0` and `1` and not `1` and `2`.

**But the proper would be to do it with `XAML` and `DataBinding`!**

Comment: thanks, yes, I changed the solution back to using XAML and instead using txt_ApplicationId.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; for each element controlling if they should appear or not